# Probability of wrong-sized boxes

Tags: probability

The cross-sectional area of plastic tubing for use in pulmonary resuscitators is normally distributed with $μ= 12.5 {mm}^2$ and $\sigma=0.2{mm}^2$.

When the area is less than $12.0 {mm}^2$ or greater than $13.0 {mm}^2$, the tube does not ﬁt
properly. If the tubes are shipped in boxes of one thousand, how many wrong-sized tubes per box can doctors expect to ﬁnd?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to do calculations with a normal distribution?

Comment: The approach is the same as [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341873/how-do-i-answer-this-statistics-question).  How many standard deviations are acceptable in each direction?

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation is $0.2$. Note that $13.0$ is $2.5$ standard deviation units **up** from the mean, while $12.0$ is $2.5$ standard deviation units down from the mean.

Look up $2.5$ in a table of the standard normal. The table entry is $0.9938$. So the probability that a standard normal is $\gt 2.5$ is approximately $0.0062$. So the probability that a standard normal is $2.5$ or more away  form $0$ is approximately $0.0124$.

This means that the probability a tube is bad is $\approx 0.0124$.

Now assume that the sizes of the tubes in a box are **independent**. Note that this is a dubious assumption.

Under that assumption, multiply the probability of bad by $1000$ to get the mean number of bad tubes in a batch of $1000$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. You need $P(12\le X \le 13)=P(2.5 \le \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le 2.5)=2P(Z<2.5)$, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. The last quantity could be computed from the tables. This probability must be multiplied by 1000 to get the expected number of badly fitting boxes.